# Why when doing a template, save stops working?

Tags: 7, theming

In the website I'm building I have to develop a template of the editing page for a certain content type (I did it in page--contentType.tpl.php (in my case page--movilidad.tpl.php).

It was a bit hard but after all (I had to rearrange all fields so I had to print field by field and so), I could manage to print all the fields needed and now looks exactly as I wanted but.... The save button to apply the changes (also the delete one) of the content type that we modify, does not work xD.

I'm quite amazed because I don't get why doing the following does not work

```
print render($page['content']['system_main']['actions']);
```

but for example, printing a block works fine as it should...

```
print render($page['content']['block_47']);
```

and the first ($page['content']['system_main']['actions']), shows exactly as it should, but it doesn't do any when I press the Save button. But when doing

```
print render($page['content']);
```

Shows all that should show in the page and it works fine.

What I am missing? I probably have a concept error because I can't see why is not working.

Comment: What do you expect the buttons to do exactly? If you render them without the surrounding form, they obviously can't submit the form, so......

Comment: @Clive well, I expect them to do same behavior as the would do normally but I have no idea how to print it with the whole behavior. What I want is to work as it works with print render($page['content']);

Comment: HTML buttons on their own don't do anything. If you want them to submit a form, you'll need them to be in the form, meaning you'll need to render the form as well. If you want them to run some javascript, you need to wire them up to some javascript. Drupal will happily render what you tell it to, there are valid uses cases for rendering buttons outside of the form, but naturally it can't change how HTML works

Comment: @Clive Yes you're right. Then my question is how do I print the form to make it work as it should? My problem mainly is not javascript or html, is doing a template correctly to make it work as it should but rearranging the fields position and so.

Comment: Yeah I don't envy you that job, it's not fun. You either need to wrap a significant portion of the page in the form tags a la ASP, or maybe don't move them, hide them altogether with CSS, and wire up some proxy buttons to submit the form via javascript instead. Or something else/in the middle of that. It's basically impossible to give any specifics without knowing your theme quite well

Comment: @Clive Ok, thank you so much for your time. I will now think what to do and yes.. it's any fun so far xDDD. Thank's for your time and sharing your knowledge